# access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.sunec"

Tags: java, security, applet, access-denied

getting below access permission exception while encrypting from a applet.

Please help .

```
Error :
security: Loading Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
basic: error: null.
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RootCertStore$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RootCertStore.loadCertStore(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RootCertStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RootCertStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.ImmutableCertStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.LazyRootStore.loadJREStores(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.LazyRootStore.getTrustAnchors(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.getValidationState(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.sunec")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:60)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:58)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC.<clinit>(SunEC.java:58)
    ... 69 more"
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@c4f9e6
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Comment: *"access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.sunec")"* Is the applet digitally signed and declaring `all-permissions`?

Comment: Yes Andrew. Thank you for your reply.my  applet is selft signed applet. below is my manifest file entry. 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: Bloom
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: Bloom
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
................

Comment: *"my applet is selft signed applet"*  The JRE won't trust 'self signed' any longer.  Get a valid digital certificate.